# ReactJS - setting a variable and printing in render giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning 'React.JS'. As far as I know a `class` has properties and methods. Now, I can create one property and then use it in render function. I am unable to understand what wrong am I doing here?

**Snippet:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Main extends Component {

    let name = "John";

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
            {name}
        </div>
      }
}

export default Main;
```

**Error:**

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: remove `let` from variable declaration

Comment: I don't know what is the trend now of just downvoting. Why can't I put let there? I am simply declaring a property. That's all !

Comment: If you want to use react, please look into properties and state.
Btw, a class attribute isn't defined by let in javascript
Also, you clearly did not look into tutorials of react. Please do it will help you greatly.

Comment: Yah, but why not. In javascript we have kept using var for variable declaration. Inside class, I am doing the same!

Comment: A React component when declared as a class component, it is an [ES6 Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), so almost everything is defined inside the constructor.

Comment: Normally, You use `props` and `state` in the React. And if we want any other declaration we use `const` in general. If you declare a variable as a `const` then you can use it by name only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a variable like that because it's not permitted in the class definition. You *can* use [(experimental) field declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations) (sometimes also called class properties) but you don't declare them with `var`, `let`, or `const` - you just add them to the class. Ensure you use the `this` context to refer to them.

```
export default class Main extends Component {

  name = 'John';

  render() {
    return <div>{this.name}</div>
  }

}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-bush-dgdnt)

The alternative to a class component is [a function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). There's less boilerplate, and you can define variables like you would in any other function:

```
export default function Main() {

  const name = "John";

  return <div>{name}</div>;

}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cannon-mzisi)

Comment: But, why can't I do same for the 'class component'? Any reason? I am simply declaring a variable via 'let' and then using it in render() function --- what's wrong in that?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should return inside your `render`. 
Secondly you can't directly assign variables in javascript classes. You should assign them inside some methods(constructor, render ...). If you want to assign some variables, I would suggest dot you to use `state` [docs for state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).
If you don't want to use it then you can simply assign variables in your render function or assign them as a global variable outside of your class.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are using the `class` component. So you have to declare `name` in `constructor` and use `this.name` in `render` method like below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.name = "John";
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
            {this.name}
        </div>
      }
}

export default Main;
```

If you are working with `functional` component then you can directly define variable in function as you already doing it.

```
import React from 'react';

function Main() {
    let name = "John";
    return <div>{name}</div>
}

export default Main;
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Hello good answer but just to clarify, you don't "have" to assign them in constructor. You can do but not have to.

Comment: If you are working with `class` component then either you have to define variable globally in constructor via `this.abc` or you can define variable in method via `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: Yes I know that. But you said in your answer as we have to assign them in constructor. I was just saying there are other ways define a variable other than inside constructor.

Comment: Yes you can do it.